# resume from suspend causing disk errors on SSD Ubuntu 18.10 Mate

Tags: suspend, ssd, 18.10, resume

I've confirmed now that this only happens on resume from suspend.  I've spent the last 2 weeks always powering off my machine and I never get any disk errors.  If I let the machine suspend however, I will get drive errors preventing boot.  I can fix the errors with fsck but clearly something is wrong.

Drive is a Samsung SSD 840 Pro, latest firmware applied.
Ubuntu 18.10 Mate.  Full disk encryption, formatted ext4 with luks/lvm

I found one similar question, but no other info.
Thanks in advance.

@heynnema:  I don't dual boot.  Just Ubuntu (mate 18.10)

**Output of blkid:**

```
/dev/mapper/sda5_crypt: UUID="nPD3Z3-EfG1-7Rhk-2T0t-cPt3-SwJs-O5RUZq" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UUID="c1d939f0-d572-4861-878f-d0c68b43c699" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: UUID="f5b6186b-246e-426c-898c-21e199128666" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="3064c363-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="a2efd4e0-2506-477f-b8ed-2b29d4a82ec2" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="3064c363-05"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="85100b0b-1c52-4be8-ba88-d9dcf74bd086" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="00073e4b-01"
/dev/sdb5: UUID="cb0e2499-918c-4643-b588-9f81999cfb03" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="00073e4b-05"
/dev/sr1: UUID="4afdfb0f00000000" LABEL="WD SmartWare" TYPE="udf" PTTYPE="mac"
/dev/sdd1: LABEL="500GB WD" UUID="299a9fe7-1129-4b55-b08b-3bc7b3be34a6" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="00052a88-01"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: UUID="c963d24c-3abd-44fb-848e-f1e20e7adfb8" TYPE="swap"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
... 
/dev/loop20: TYPE="squashfs"
```

**fstab:**

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    noatime,errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
#UUID=f5b6186b-246e-426c-898c-21e199128666 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
#UUID=a2efd4e0-2506-477f-b8ed-2b29d4a82ec2  /boot   crypto_LUKS defaults    0   2
UUID=f5b6186b-246e-426c-898c-21e199128666   /boot   ext4    defaults    0   2
```

**conf.d/resume:**

```
RESUME=UUID=c963d24c-3abd-44fb-848e-f1e20e7adfb8
```

**free**

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        1.4G        2.3G        181M        4.0G        5.8G
Swap:          979M          0B        979M
```

Comment: Edit your question and add the output from `sudo blkid`, `cat /etc/fstab`, and `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`, and `free -h`. Do you dual-boot with Windows? Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema.edited as requested. Thx

Comment: The only thing that I see is that your swap is too small, especially if you're actually hibernating. You should resize it to 4G for normal use, or about 10G if you're hibernating.

Comment: I guess that could make sense - because I can suspend and resume sometimes w/out error.  I don't hibernate.  I'll try increasing swap and see if that makes any difference.  I think it has something to do with encryption - this is my first time doing full disk crypto ... never had these issues before.  ( but again, maybe you're right and it is SWAP size )

Comment: Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I will  - thanks again so much - it might take a bit.  Just looked into managing the partitions with encryption ... not exactly simple!  LOL.  I'm used to just using "disks" and doing what I need by dragging a slider.  Oh well.  One step forward two steps back.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Yes, unless you're in a corporate/government environment, encryption never made much sense to me, for exactly that reason, and for ease of recovery.